# Struggling to Calculate Integral of Differential Forms

Tags: differential-forms, multiple-integral, submanifold

The problem states this: "Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^{\infty}$ function. Orient the graph $X = \Gamma_f$ of $f$ by requiring that the diffeomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{R}^n \to X\quad x \mapsto (x,f(x))$ be orientation preserving. Given a bounded open set $U$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ compute the Riemannian volume of the image $X_U = \phi(U)$ of $U$ in $X$ as integral over $U$." In a previous problem I proved that $\phi^*\sigma = \left(1+\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\right)^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}dx_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_n$ where $\sigma$ is the volume form, so I know that can be substituted in. But from there I am confused on how to actually calculate the integral. My book doesn't really give any help on how to calculate it, but still asks this problem. This also comes before the proof of Stokes's. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by calculate the integral?

Comment: @ArcticChar Well the problem asks that I "compute the Riemannian volume of the image $X_U=\phi(U)$ of $U$ in $X$ as an integral over $U$." I'm assuming there's some kind of numerical answer, but I'm not entirely sure, my book gives very little context.

Comment: I wonder how you get a numerical answer, if $f$ is not explicitly given. If you want something in terms of an integral over $U$, just write $\int_U \left(1+\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\right)^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}dx_1 \cdots dx_n$ and you are done.

Comment: @ArcticChar That's why I'm so confused, the question is super unclear. I'll probably just go with that. Thank you very much for your help!